# React-router v4 this.props.history.push(...) not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm trying to route programatically using `this.props.history.push(..)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the router:

```
import {
 BrowserRouter as Router,
 Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
 <Route path="/customers/" exact component={CustomersList} />
 <Route path="/customers/:id" exact component="{Customer} />
</Router>
```

In CustomerList, a list of customers is rendered. Clicking on a customer (li) should make the application route to Customer:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Customers extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

 handleCustomerClick(customer) {
   this.props.history.push(`/customers/${customer.id}`);
 }

 render() {
   return(
    <ul>
      { this.props.customers.map((c) =>
        <li onClick={() => this.handleCustomerClick(c)} key={c.id}>
          {c.name}
        </li> 
    </ul>
  )

 }
}

//connect to redux to get customers

CustomersList = withRouter(CustomersList);
export default CustomersList;
```

The code is partial but illustrates perfectly the situation.
What happens is that the browser's address bar changes accordingly to history.push(..), but the view does not update, Customer component is not rendered and CustomersList is still there. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I do believe that what is really happening is that both components match and both components are being rendered. Could you check if both component are executing their respective `componentDidMount` please?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca They have `exact` on both routes

Comment: Yes, I know, But I've faced similar issues. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: You can take a look at [these examples](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf). I guess you have to use a `Switch` component to match what you want.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca like he suggested , i think the problem is that the two routes have the same name , i countered the same problem , just change customers to customer , and give it a try

Comment: I was missing `exact` on my `Router`

Answer (score 26):

So I came to this question hoping for an answer but to no avail. I have used

```
const { history } = this.props;
history.push("/thePath")
```

In the same project and it worked as expected.
Upon further experimentation and some comparing and contrasting, I realized that this code **will not run if it is called within the nested component**. Therefore only the rendered page component can call this function for it to work properly.

Find Working Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmj6jw1v3j)

- history: v4.7.2
- react: v16.0.0
- react-dom: v16.0.0
- react-router-dom:
  v4.2.2

Comment: Given how fast react-router, (and for that matter, the whole JS ecosystem moves), it will improve your answer if you include what version you're on, and your answer will be amazing if you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Services like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) should help with that.

Comment: I get history.push( is not a function

Comment: IMHO this is the same as this.pros.history.pus(). You just put it into other variable. both undefined to me....

Answer (score 14):

It seems things have changed around a bit in the latest version of react router. You can now access history via the context. `this.context.history.push('/path')`

Also see the replies to the this github issue: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059

Comment: A better way to do this is to use `withRouter` HOC. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Answer (score 9):

You can try to load the child component with history. to do so, pass 'history' through props. Something like that:

```
  return (
  <div>
    <Login history={this.props.history} />
    <br/>
    <Register/>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: looks like this is the way... and it is very sad

Answer (score 9):

For me (react-router v4, react v16) the problem was that I had the navigation component all right:

```
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class MainMenu extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
            ...
            <NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
            ...
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(MainMenu);
```

Both using either

```
to="/contact"
```

or

```
OnClick={() => this.props.history.push('/contact')};
```

The behavior was still the same - the URL in browser changed but wrong components were rendered, the router was called with the same old URL.

The culprit was in the router definition. I had to move the MainMenu component as a child of the Router component!

```
// wrong placement of the component that calls the router
<MainMenu history={this.props.history} />
<Router>
   <div>
     // this is the right place for the component!
     <MainMenu history={this.props.history} />
     <Route path="/" exact component={MainPage} />
     <Route path="/contact/" component={MainPage} />
   </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest 's match via the **withRouter** higher-order component. **withRouter** will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'; 
// you can also import "withRouter" from 'react-router-dom';

class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        const { match, location, history } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>
                <button onClick={() => history.push('/')}>{'Home'}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default withRouter(Example)
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like an old question but still relevant.

I think it is a [blocked update](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) issue.

The main problem is the new URL (route) is supposed to be rendered by the same component(`Costumers`) as you are currently in (current URL).

So solution is rather simple, make the window url as a prop, so react has a chance to detect the prop change (therefore the url change), and act accordingly.

A nice usecase described in the official react blog called [Recommendation: Fully uncontrolled component with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key).

So the solution is to change from

`render() {
   return(
    <ul>`

to

`render() {
   return(
    <ul key={this.props.location.pathname}>`

So whenever the location changed by react-router, the component got scrapped (by react) and a new one gets initiated with the right values (by react).

Oh, and pass the `location` as prop to the component(`Costumers`) where the redirect will happen if it is not passed already.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar symptoms, but my problem was that I was nesting `BrowserRouter`

---

**Do not nest `BrowserRouter`**, because the `history` object will refer to the nearest `BrowserRouter` parent. So when you do a `history.push(targeturl)` and that **targeturl** it's not in that particular `BrowserRouter` it won't match any of it's route, so it will not load any sub-component.

#### Solution

Nest the `Switch` without wrapping it with a `BrowserRouter`

---

## Example

#### Let's consider this `App.js` file

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/nestedrouter" component={NestedRouter}  />
    <Route exact path="/target" component={Target}  />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

#### Instead of doing this in the `NestedRouter.js` file

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/nestedrouter/" component={NestedRouter}  />
    <Route exact path="/nestedrouter/subroute" component={SubRoute}  />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

#### Simply remove the `BrowserRouter` from `NestedRouter.js` file

```js
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/nestedrouter/" component={NestedRouter}  />
    <Route exact path="/nestedrouter/subroute" component={SubRoute}  />
  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this scenario. You have `App.jsx` as the root file for you ReactJS SPA. In it your `render()` looks similar to this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/comp" component={MyComponent} />
</Switch>
```

then, you should be able to use `this.props.history` inside `MyComponent` without a problem. Let's say you are rendering `MySecondComponent` inside `MyComponent`, in that case you need to call it in such manner:

```
<MySecondComponent {...props} />
```

which will pass the props from `MyComponent` down to `MySecondComponent`, thus making `this.props.history` available in `MySecondComponent`

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the **Customers** Component not the **CustomerList**.

```
    CustomersList = withRouter(Customers);
    export default CustomersList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a class component but in case you decide to switch to functional component or encountered the same issue with a functional component in your application, you can fix this issue by using the **"useHistory"** hook API by *react-router-dom.*

*Example of usage:*

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Customers = ({customer}) => {
   let history = useHistory();

   const handleCustomerClick = (customer) => {
     history.push(`/customers/${customer.id}`);
   }

  return (
    //some JSX here
  );
};
```

You may find the official documentation here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Answer (score 0):

Beginner's mistake when working with routing is the importance of using `withRouter` directly with the component and not put any other high order component in between (or at least one that doest not know to push the `props.history` to its children:

**Wrong:** `export default withRouter(withErrorHandler(Foo));`

**Correct:** `export default withErrorHandler(withRouter(Foo));`

Answer (score 0):

`const navigate=useNavigate();

navigate(/customers/${customer.id}); `

Answer (score -3):

Don't use with Router.

```
handleSubmit(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err,values)=>{
      if(!err){
        this.setState({
            visible:false
        });
        this.props.form.resetFields();
        console.log(values.username);
        const path = '/list/';
        this.props.history.push(path);
      }
   })
}
```

It works well.

Answer (score -3):

You need to bind `handleCustomerClick`:

```
class Customers extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleCustomerClick = this.handleCustomerClick(this)
  }
```

Comment: this.handleCustomerClick = this.handleCustomerClick.bind(this) did the trick for me.

Answer (score -6):

```
this.props.history.push(`/customers/${customer.id}`, null);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be great if you could add a little bit of an explanation about why you think this call solves the problem asked about in the question.