# Redirect to new page on Submit: this.props.history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-props

I'm trying to build a simple job board, front end in ReactJS.

I've using github jobs API to pull my API data in ComponentDidMount.

I have a handleChange, on a form, which returns jobs results when I enter a job search keyword.  Such as "developer" jobs, in "new york".
This all works.

On Submit though, I want to push my data, to a new page - "job results". Like you'd see on a normal job website.  Enter a job search and the results load on a new page.

I'm trying to use this.props.history.push, to push my locations data stored in set and return this to a page with the url "/jobresults".

This isn't working though.  I'm not getting an error. Just nothing happens and my page remains as it is.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my app.js code.

Thanks, 
Reena

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

import Jobs from './components/Jobs';
import HomePageResults from './components/HomePageResults';
import JobResults from './components/JobResults';
import JobDescription from './components/JobDescription';
import ApplyNow from './components/ApplyNow';
import Confirmation from './components/Confirmation';
import './assets/scss/main.scss';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';



class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('CONSTRUCTOR');

    this.state = {
      jobs: [],
      searchData: '',
      cityData: 'new york',
      locations: []
    };
  }



  // FUNCTION TO CALL API IS WORKING
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Component Did Mount: WORKING');
    axios.get('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=')

      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.slice(0,4));
        this.setState({ jobs: res.data.slice(0,4) });
      });
  }


  // HANDCHANGE FOR JOB SEARCH
  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ searchData: e.target.value });
  }


  // HANDLE CHANGE FOR LOCATION SEARCH
  handleChangeLocation = (e) => {
    console.log('location', e.target.value);
    this.setState({ cityData: e.target.value });
  }


  // HANDLE SUBMIT
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.searchData);
    axios.get(`https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=${this.state.searchData}&location=${this.state.cityData}`)


      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ locations: res.data });
        console.log('location data', this.state.locations);
      })
      .then(() => this.props.history.push('/jobresults'));
  }



  render() {
    return(


      <main>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <section>
            <Navbar />

            <Switch>
              <Route path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
              <Route path="/jobresults" component={JobResults} />
              <Route path="/jobdescription" component={JobDescription} />
              <Route path="/apply" component={ApplyNow} />
              <Route path="/confirmation" component={Confirmation} />
            </Switch>

            <Header
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              handleChangeLocation={this.handleChangeLocation}
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            />
            <HomePageResults jobs={this.state.jobs}/>
          </section>
        </BrowserRouter>

      </main>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Could it be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312437/react-router-v4-this-props-history-push-not-working where the history object has to referenced from the outer context?

Comment: is the url updating at least? just not re-rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) are just available in the components given to your `Route` components, so you cannot use `this.props.history` in your `App` component.

You could instead create the `history` object manually and give that to the `Router`, and that way be able to use the `history` object where you see fit.

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

const history = createHistory();

class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .get(
        `https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=${
          this.state.searchData
        }&location=${this.state.cityData}`
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ locations: res.data });
        history.push("/jobresults");
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Router history={history}>{/* ... */}</Router>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will give this a go.  In your <Router> though, what should I put in {/* ... */}?  IE - what code should I write here? I'm happy to give this a go myself, I just wondered why you left it blank. Thank you.

Comment: @ReenaVerma You're welcome! `{/* ... */}` was just a way to make my answer a bit shorter. What you have inside the `BrowserRouter` will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Hey @tholle, i haven't had a chance to get to it yet, sorry - i'm just having to prioritise a code test. I'll definitely have a quick play around tonight.  :( . I well let you know as soon as I've worked with it.  Gimme a few hours - thank you :)

Comment: Hey @Tholle - sorry for the delay in coming back to you.  It's been a crazy few weeks, but this worked PERFECTLY!  Thank you!! :)