# Programmatically navigate while using HashRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using HashRouter for my routes in a react.js app. I then have a function which does the following:

```
this.props.history.push('/somePath');
```

The problem is, ever since I started using `HashRouter`, the page doesn't push to that path when that function gets called.

I logged `this.props.history`, and `push` was there.

How can I programmatically navigate while using `HashRouter`?

Note: I used `withRouter`

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
// Other imports

class App extends Component {
    navigate = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/route1');
        console.log(this.props.history);
    };

    render() {    
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Header />

                <HashRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            path="/route1"
                            exact
                            render={() => (
                                <FirstRoute someSetting='setting1'/>
                            )}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/route2"
                            exact
                            render={() => (
                                <SecondRoute anotherSetting='Really Cool'/>
                            )}
                        />
                        <Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
                        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <HomePage someSettings='Home Page' />} />
                        <Redirect to="/404" />
                    </Switch>
                </HashRouter>

                <BottomBar />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: can you share some code of the component where you tried to implement the navigation?

Comment: @LaurensDeprost Sorry about that... Just updated it

Comment: @Jessica when `navigate` function is called ? in which portion of code is called ?

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez It gets called from another file.

Comment: @Jessica You never pass `navigate` as a prop to anything.  Can you also provide the code in the other file that is calling it?

Comment: can you post the code where the navigate method is called ? to be able to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [React-router v4 this.props.history.push(…) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312437/react-router-v4-this-props-history-push-not-working), see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53968871/3378034) there