# /undefined when clicking browsers go back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React app I'm using 2 types of links - some of them are created by Link elements and some are onClick's 
When I navigate by Links everything works fine, but when I click any programmatically navigating element and then want to use browser "go back" button I get /undefinded in my browser address bar and blank page. Any ideas what can be wrong?

Here is my example "programmaticall" link:

```
<div onClick={()=>{props.history.push(`/${props.target}`)}}>{props.text}></div>
```

Comment: Isn't `props.target` undefined in the `onClick` handler ?

Comment: No, it's always defined, otherwise links wouldn't work. Navigating "forward" works fine, the problem occures when I want to go back with browser "go back" button.

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312437/react-router-v4-this-props-history-push-not-working