# Programmatically navigating : React Router V4+ Typescript giving error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

Error while programmatically navigating using react router v4 and Typescript:

> Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>

I want to redirect to a particular path on success or failure of a API call. But Unable to do that.

### Router code

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Switch , Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component<{}, {}>  {
 render()
 {
    <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Login}/>
          <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/test' component={Test}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  }
}
export default App;
```

### Component

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import * as React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

  handleSubmit = async() => {
            //code for API calls
            this.props.history.push("/home") // error at this line
   }

  render() {
     // Form with validations and a submit handler
  }
}
export default  withRouter(Test);
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312437/react-router-v4-this-props-history-push-not-working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import the `import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";`
The RouteComponentProps interface has the props you're looking for.

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}, C extends StaticContext = StaticContext, S = H.LocationState> {
  history: H.History;
  location: H.Location<S>;
  match: match<Params>;
  staticContext?: C;
}
```

Your component will look something like this:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import * as React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
interface IProps {}

type HomeProps = IProps & RouteComponentProps;

interface IState {}

class Home extends React.Component<HomeProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: HomeProps) {
    super(props);
  }
  private handleSubmit = async () => {
    //code for API calls
    this.props.history.push("/home");
  };

  public render(): any {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
}
export const HomeComponent = withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much

Comment: how do you call the component while passing props?

Answer (score -4):

Just declare it any whenever you run into problems - works everytime - typescript, unfortunately, is a big ball of mud.

Like so:

```
const Home: React.FC = (props:any) => {
```

Comment: This is a very bad practice, please try to avoid `any` type at all cost. Otherwise, it means that you use TypeScript for no reason.