# How to go next page in react component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am developing a simple login application using REACTJS, NODEJS. I am receiving status code from the backend (like 201, 202) and match them in **switch case**, Now I want to try when **Case 201** is **true** user **route/redirect to next page** in the application, but when I use **history.push('path')** the function I get **TypeError: this is undefined**, So anyone guides me in this issue.

```
    class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      
      super(props)
      
      this.state = {
            username:'',   
            password:''
            
      }
    }
    
    usernameHandler=event=>{
      this.setState({
        username:event.target.value,
        
      })
    }
    passwordHandler=event=>{
      this.setState({
      password:event.target.value
      })
    }
    submitHandler=event=>{
      var data = new FormData();
      let {username,password}=this.state;
      
      data.append("username",username)
      data.append("password",password)
      
      event.preventDefault()
            console.log("----------------------",this.state);
            axios.post('http://localhost:8080/note', data,{
          headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        }).then(function(res){
          console.log("----------------------response",res);
          var {history}=this.props;  //<=TypeError: this is undefined
          let statuscode=res.status;
          console.log('status code is :',statuscode)
          switch(statuscode){
            case 201: 
              console.log("case 1")
              history.push('./Datajc')  //<=here is problem , how we go to next page  
              alert('login successful') 
              break;
    
            case 202: 
              console.log('case 2')
              alert('login unsuccessful') 
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }).catch(function(err){
          console.log('errror....',err);
        })
    }
      render() {
        const {username, password}=this.state
            return (
            <div className="custom_wrapper">
                <div className="custom_form-wrapper">
                  <h1>SIGN IN INTO YOUR ACCOUNT</h1>
                  <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler} >
                    <div className="custom_username" >
                      <label htmlFor="username">User Name</label>
                      <input className='custom_input'
                        placeholder="example@email.com"
                        type="text"
                        name="username"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={this.usernameHandler}
                      /><br></br>
                      
                    
                      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                      <input className='custom_input'
                        placeholder="password"
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={this.passwordHandler}
                      />
                      <button type="submit" >Login</button>
                    </div>
                    
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
              </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default Login
```

Comment: First please format your code correctly so others can read more easily. And have you tried to install PIL module?

Comment: Install `Pillow` module.

Comment: Are you using `react-router`?

Comment: @technogeek1995 Yes I use react-router in App.js which is the main file, this is login.js how I goto another page when user login successully that is case 1 is executed

Comment: You need to pass in `history` as a `prop`. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013844/1913185. So `history.push('./Datajc')` becomes `this.props.history.push('./Datajc')`.

Comment: @technogeek1995 Now I getting an error **TypeError: this is undefined**

Answer (score -1):

In this case, your callback in the `.then`, is clobbering the react component's class `this` with it's own `this`. In JavaScript functions defined with `function () {}`, `this` is always scoped locally to the function. Therefore, when you resolved your `history` issue by doing `this.props.history`, you still didn't have access to it because of the way the callback is written. In React, you should prefer to write functions like `() => {}` because the reference to `this` from the class does not get overwritten (as it would when you write a function like `function () {}`).

```
submitHandler = event => {
  const data = new FormData();

  const { username, password } = this.state;
  data.append("username", username)
  data.append("password", password)

  event.preventDefault()
  console.log("----------------------", this.state);
  axios.post('http://localhost:8080/note', data, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log("----------------------response", res);
    const statuscode = res.status;
    console.log('status code is :', statuscode)
    switch (statuscode) {
      case 201:
        console.log("case 1")
        this.props.history.push('./Datajc') 
        alert('login successful')
        break;
      case 202:
        console.log('case 2')
        alert('login unsuccessful')
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('errror....', err);
  })
}
```